# How can i access jquery functions defined in assets javascript foler to my js.erb extention under specific controller?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am having a **custom.js** file in **app/assets** folder which was created when I generated a **custom controller**. Now i have created a **custom_action.js.erb** file under **app/views/customs** which is a part of custom controller views. This custom_action.js.erb file is used to handle ajax respose.

Now the problem that I face is that I cant access functions defined in **custom.js** to **custom_action.js.erb**. This is my *custom.js* file.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     function someFunction() {
            // do something              
     }
}
```

And this is my **custom_action.js.erb** file.

```
$('#selector').onClick{
    someFunction();  //This is where I want to access the custom.js function
}
```

Right now I am repeating the function in both custom.js and custom_action.js.erb file. Is there a way to avoid this repeat and make the function accessible when I define it in *custom.js* file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to wrap a function in `$(document).ready`. When you do that it only has scope within that particular ready callback handler function. Also jQuery has no `onClick` method.

`$(document).ready` is only needed for code that will run immediately on page load that will need to locate elements in the page.

```
function someFunction() {
            // do something              
     }

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#selector').click(function(){
         someFunction();
    });
      /* or */
      $('#selector').click(someFunction);
});
```

Comment: If I define a function test() outside the $(document).ready and someone else on my team defines his own test() function outside the $(document).ready, will it end up in a conflict? Thats the reason why I kept it inside $(document).ready.

Comment: can certainly create it within another object and keep all global functions within that object to avoid those sorts of conflicts. Problem you described however is a simple matter of closure and scope

Comment: Thanks. I am following that procedure. Now I can access functions in both files.